# Access to file size of a TranslateRemoteModel

Tags: android, google-mlkit

Is there a way though the API or otherwise access file size of individual translate models for showing in an user interface?

I couldn't find anything in docs and tried to look into the app-specific folders for model files but it was empty even though I have two models already downloaded.